# toggleClass point a to point B not a smooth transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a hover toggleClass. I have -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s; transition: all ease 0.8s; on the toggleClass', but not sure why they aren't transitioning smoothly. The Icon kind of just jumps to the left and the text doesn't fade in slowly (I am assuming that will be done with CSS). Any help to make the transitions smoother would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

```js
$("#clicker1").hover(function() {
            $('.shower').toggleClass('shower-active'); 
            $('.design').toggleClass('design-active', 300);
        
            $('.description').toggleClass('description-active', 300);  
            $('.iconSmaller').toggleClass('iconSmaller-active', 400);
 });
```

```css
.col-t {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #035C7A;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
    
    
}


.col:hover{
    color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -400px 0 0 #035C7A;

}


.col-t:hover{
    color: white;
    background: #035C7A;
}

.col-t .descritption:hover{
  color: #035C7A;
}

.box {
  background-color: #218D9B;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.iconSmaller {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;  
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-active{
  display:none;
}


.iconSmaller-active{
  width:200px !important;
  height:200px !important;
  text-align:left;
  padding-top:0px !important;
  float:left;
  padding-left:10px;
  display:block;
  color: white;
}

.shower {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;  
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.shower-active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -400px 0 0 #444;
  height: 220px;
  color: black !important;
}

.description {
  display:none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;  
  transition: all 1s ease;
  }
 
  .description-active {
    display:block;
    color:white;
    float:right;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section style="width:80%; margin:auto;"> 
    <div class="col-t col1 shower" id="clicker1">
        <div class="iconSmaller">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size:175px;padding-top:30px;"></i>
            <h1 class="design">DRAW</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
            <p> LOREM<br><br>IPSUM<br><br>TEXT</p>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here that is irrelevant to the question; can you please pare it down to just the portion you're having trouble with?

Comment: (That said, the gist of the answer is going to be that you're trying to transition between properties that can't be animated, such as from "display:none" to "display:block".  You can only animate continuous values, such as opacity; there's no value that is halfway between "none" and "block".)

Comment: I have taken out the media queries. Then how would I animate with CSS to transition the icon and fade in the text?

Comment: Easiest way to fade in the text would be using `opacity` instead of `display`. To animate the icon positioning, you'll have to stop using floats and etc so you can animate continuous values such as `margin` or pixel position -- there's still a lot of extraneous code here so I can't easily see exactly which properties you need to revise.   (Incidentally from what I can tell you don't need javascript for any of this; `:hover` rules should be sufficient.)

Comment: I am concerned that removing the floats will effect my column code but I will give it a try! thank you.